# I am using bottomsheet inside expandable recylerview it is not scrolling, bottom sheet scroll only works

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have bottom sheet contains two fragments, In filter fragment I’m loading the expandable reyclerview ,but does not scrolling

Layout is like

```
NestedScrollview
  -Linearlayout
    -Reycycler view
     - Reycycler view (Inside adapter I’m loading one recycler view
```

Can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Kotlin

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

Java

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

With this you disable the scroll of the recycler and use that of the NestedScrollView.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onScrollListener in recycler view and disabled the parent scroll view using

```
 childScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
            val shouldScroll = oldScrollY > scrollY || scrollY > oldScrollY
            v.parent.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(shouldScroll)

            if (scrollY == (v?.getChildAt(0)?.measuredHeight ?: 0) - (v?.measuredHeight ?: 0)) {
                //logic for recyclerview reached at bottom 
            }
        })
```

Here I am using nested scroll view inside recycler view which is inside scroll view.